# Html elements are ignoring name property

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm building a Form with the following code

```
<h1>Opzoeken</h1>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
new AjaxOptions { 
    HttpMethod = "get",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "ZoekResultaat" }))
{
<input type="search" name="searchterm" /> <br />
<input type="submit" name="Externe" /> 
<input type="submit" name="Leveranciers" /> 
<input type="submit" name="Contracten" /> 
}
```

But no matter what browser I debug in the buttons always have "Verzenden" instead of the assigned name.

detais: it's an mvc app and I checked the css nothing is changing the name off the buttons in there.

Comment: Just curious, do you need all three submit bottons together?

Comment: The idea is the user types in a search term and choose 1 of 3 options which then each search a different section. so yes i need the 3 buttons. don't need to be submit but got same issue with a normal button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value=""` to override the text the button displays, `Verzenden` is default for the Dutch language, which is automatically detected. For English people it will show `Submit`, etc.

```
<input type="search" name="searchterm" /> <br />
<input type="submit" name="Externe" value="Externe" /> 
<input type="submit" name="Leveranciers" value="Leveranciers" /> 
<input type="submit" name="Contracten" value="Contracten" />
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5DVa4/)

Comment: Thank you, this solves it. not sure why all the examples I found did it withot the value parameter though.